# Time conversion from pm to am in Angular 6 component

Tags: angular, datepicker, datetimepicker, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a form in angular in which we have 2 input fields `StartTime` and `EndTime`. In `StartTime` if we input date and time and it should automatically be updated in `Endtime` with '+' 1 hour in time.

It is working fine, but when it has to convert from am to pm it does not convert. The time value in  `this.endTimeValue` while debugging is fine but it dipslays the wrong value in the view (`EndTime`) while binding.

**Html file:**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit(myGroup.value)">
    <div class="row row-time">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <label for="StartTime">Start Time</label>
            <input type="datetime-local"  name="StartTime" class="form-control" formControlName="StartTime">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
            <label for="EndTime">End Time</label>
            <input type="datetime-local"  name="endTime1" class="form-control" formControlName="EndTime" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">
            Submit Query
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Component file (ts):**

```ts
myGroup: FormGroup;
startTimeValue: any;
endTimeValue : string ;

constructor(private formbuilder:FormBuilder, 
              private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.myGroup = this.formbuilder.group({
    TableName:['', Validators.required],
    CorrelationId:['', Validators.required],
    StartTime:[null, Validators.required],
    EndTime:[null, Validators.required],
    ClientName:['', Validators.required]
  });
}


submit(form){
  this.startTimeValue = form.StartTime;
  var time = this.startTimeValue;

  if(time !== null)
  {
    debugger;
    var x = new Date(time);
    x.setHours(x.getHours() + 1);
    this.endTimeValue = x.LocaleString();
    debugger;
    this.myGroup.patchValue({
      EndTime: this.datePipe.transform(this.endTimeValue,"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm",'+0530')
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what should be the input and output?

Comment: The datetime-local input type specifies a local time without time zone, and the internal representation of the value is in ISO 8601 conformant format, which has no AM/PM. It is left to implementations to decide what localized format might be used in the user interface. Whether they have AM/PM designator is outside the author’s control.

Comment: if suppose startTime is 11:00 PM then EndTime should be 12:00 AM but it is dispalying 12:00PM

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at moment.js

Here is the link for moment.js
https://momentjs.com/

You need to install it with the command:
npm install moment --save

And then you can start converting the input that user has typed, like:

```
var a = moment('2018-11-21');
a.format('LT');   // 8:59 AM
a.format('LTS');  // 8:59:09 AM
```